# What is the collation we have to use for ½ symbol in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

How to change a collation for a column , for ½ symbol in SQL Server 2008 ??

Comment: Why don't you just store the value as Unicode (`NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR`)?

Comment: If you trouble is that the value isn't *displaying* correctly, you don't have a collation problem, you have a problem with your client code inserting the value wrong, retrieving it wrong or displaying it wrong -- or any combination of these three. Try an `INSERT` statement with `N'½'` to ensure he value is correct, then see how to reproduce the display issue, then edit your question to make it about that, rather than collations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick test and for example collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS can store that symbol.

```
create table test1(
    symbol varchar(10) -- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)

insert test1(symbol) values ('½')

select * from test1

symbol
½
```

Comment: But when i copy data from table and paste in notepad i can see that  1/2 symbol is displaying in red color.And when it loads into to the application view it is displaying as ?. How to convert the already inserted data into proper format ?????

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert :Column is nvarchar(max), but still when we load and display the data in view it is displaying as ?